# What does Omni Channel do with work items when all agents are offline?

Tags: omnichannel

This seems like a very basic question but I cannot find a direct answer anywhere. Omni channel will route new work items (cases, calls, chats, etc) to agents that are online. But what happens to the cases that are created over night when we don't have anyone working? Are they stuck in the queue, or do they get reassigned automatically at some point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omnichannel has a hidden queue where it holds work items until they can be assigned to someone. The object is called [pending service routing](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.246.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_pendingservicerouting.htm)

You can find some other clues on how things work behind the scenes in the [Omni-channel developer guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/latest/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/service_presence_developer_guide.pdf)