# Does omni-channel support Lead/Case assignment even if agents are offline or not logged into Salesforce

Tags: omnichannel, lead-assignment

Not really sure if I missed it, but wanted to know if work item assignment possible even if agents are offline/not logged in to Salesforce. Checked this but not clear if that is feasible - [What does Omni Channel do with work items when all agents are offline?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/412040/what-does-omni-channel-do-with-work-items-when-all-agents-are-offline)
Thanks